# geofilt in solr returns all indexed documents instead of nearest points

Tags: solr, lucene, spatial

I'm working with solr 4.10.4 and I have indexed some documents containing the geo-coordinates for some points, I have created a fieldType called location of class: Latlon, then created a dynamic field with the suffix _coordinate to store the lat,lon values.

when querying the location with geofilt it returns all indexed documents instead of returning the nearest points within the defined distance.
this is the query 
q=*:*& fq=!geofilt sfield=location pt=37.775,-122.419 d= &wt=xml

I would be grateful if you could help me detect the cause of this problem.

Comment: How does your actual query string look? Your example is missing a lot of characters.

Comment: do you mean the syntax of the query? it is :
http://localhost:8983/solr/geospatial/select?q=*:*&
fq={!geofilt sfield=location pt=37.775,-122.419 d=20}

Comment: Have a look at the output with debugQuery=true appended - check that the filter query is actually being applied and what the end query is (maybe the space in front of fq is being interpreted..)